# selenium can't click on the hidden menu element in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I use such selenium code:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("main_menu"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action action = builder.moveToElement(button).build();
action .perform();
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(sub_menu))).click().perform();
```

I have latest version of selenium and need use IE, I tried this code in FireFox, it works.
But in IE it doesn't click on sub_menu element, it click on some space under main_menu (currently it is second item of main_menu).

How can I click on sub_menu item in IE?

Comment: Can you click if you manually use IE ? The rendering might be different on IE, preventing a click.

Comment: yes, I can click manually

Comment: It may be a timing issue, try the selenium command to wait until element is visible maybe.

Comment: I have try waits but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if the same xpath what you have used in firefox is working fine in IE also?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with javascript:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', element)
```

where element is hidden element, you want to click on.